# instantly ratelimited for no reason discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to make a Discord.py bot on Repl.it, but the moment I ran it, I got ratelimited.

```
from keep_alive import keep_alive
import discord
import discord.ext
from discord.utils import get
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
from discord.ext.commands import has_permissions,  CheckFailure, check
import os
from discord_slash import SlashCommand
from discord_slash import SlashContext
from discord_slash.utils import manage_commands
# ^^ All of our necessary imports

#Define our bot
client = discord.Client()

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "!") #put your own prefix here, but it wont matter since slash commands default to /
slash = SlashCommand(client, sync_commands=True)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    await client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online, activity=discord.Game(name='Bolton FC')) #Bot status, change this to anything you like
    print("Bot online") #will print "bot online" in the console when the bot is online
    

#Send message "pong" when user sends /ping
@slash.slash(name="ping", description="Ping Pong")
async def _help(ctx: SlashContext):
    await ctx.send(content="pong!")



#Run our webserver, this is what we will ping
keep_alive()

#Run our bot
client.run(os.getenv("TOKEN"))
```

i ran this code once, and instantly got ratelimited.
this is the error i recieve

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 36, in <module>
    client.run(os.getenv("TOKEN")) 
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 718, in run
    return future.result()
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 697, in runner
    await self.start(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 660, in start
    await self.login(*args, bot=bot)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 509, in login
    await self.http.static_login(token.strip(), bot=bot)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 293, in static_login
    data = await self.request(Route('GET', '/users/@me'))
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 209, in request
    raise HTTPException(r, data)
discord.errors.HTTPException: 429 Too Many Requests (error code: 0): <!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js ie6 oldie" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js ie7 oldie" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js ie8 oldie" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en-US"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<title>Access denied | discord.com used Cloudflare to restrict access</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" id="cf_styles-css" href="/cdn-cgi/styles/main.css" />


<script>
(function(){if(document.addEventListener&&window.XMLHttpRequest&&JSON&&JSON.stringify){var e=function(a){var c=document.getElementById("error-feedback-survey"),d=document.getElementById("error-feedback-success"),b=new XMLHttpRequest;a={event:"feedback clicked",properties:{errorCode:1015,helpful:a,version:1}};b.open("POST","https://sparrow.cloudflare.com/api/v1/event");b.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json");b.setRequestHeader("Sparrow-Source-Key","c771f0e4b54944bebf4261d44bd79a1e");
b.send(JSON.stringify(a));c.classList.add("feedback-hidden");d.classList.remove("feedback-hidden")};document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(){var a=document.getElementById("error-feedback"),c=document.getElementById("feedback-button-yes"),d=document.getElementById("feedback-button-no");"classList"in a&&(a.classList.remove("feedback-hidden"),c.addEventListener("click",function(){e(!0)}),d.addEventListener("click",function(){e(!1)}))})}})();
</script>

<script defer src="https://performance.radar.cloudflare.com/beacon.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="cf-wrapper">
    <div class="cf-alert cf-alert-error cf-cookie-error hidden" id="cookie-alert" data-translate="enable_cookies">Please enable cookies.</div>
    <div id="cf-error-details" class="p-0">
      <header class="mx-auto pt-10 lg:pt-6 lg:px-8 w-240 lg:w-full mb-15 antialiased">
         <h1 class="inline-block md:block mr-2 md:mb-2 font-light text-60 md:text-3xl text-black-dark leading-tight">
           <span data-translate="error">Error</span>
           <span>1015</span>
         </h1>
         <span class="inline-block md:block heading-ray-id font-mono text-15 lg:text-sm lg:leading-relaxed">Ray ID: 7694d98e289d2d9d &bull;</span>
         <span class="inline-block md:block heading-ray-id font-mono text-15 lg:text-sm lg:leading-relaxed">2022-11-13 04:44:01 UTC</span>
        <h2 class="text-gray-600 leading-1.3 text-3xl lg:text-2xl font-light">You are being rate limited</h2>
      </header>

      <section class="w-240 lg:w-full mx-auto mb-8 lg:px-8">
          <div id="what-happened-section" class="w-1/2 md:w-full">
            <h2 class="text-3xl leading-tight font-normal mb-4 text-black-dark antialiased" data-translate="what_happened">What happened?</h2>
            <p>The owner of this website (discord.com) has banned you temporarily from accessing this website.</p>
            
          </div>

          
      </section>

      <div class="feedback-hidden py-8 text-center" id="error-feedback">
    <div id="error-feedback-survey" class="footer-line-wrapper">
        Was this page helpful?
        <button class="border border-solid bg-white cf-button cursor-pointer ml-4 px-4 py-2 rounded" id="feedback-button-yes" type="button">Yes</button>
        <button class="border border-solid bg-white cf-button cursor-pointer ml-4 px-4 py-2 rounded" id="feedback-button-no" type="button">No</button>
    </div>
    <div class="feedback-success feedback-hidden" id="error-feedback-success">
        Thank you for your feedback!
    </div>
</div>


      <div class="cf-error-footer cf-wrapper w-240 lg:w-full py-10 sm:py-4 sm:px-8 mx-auto text-center sm:text-left border-solid border-0 border-t border-gray-300">
  <p class="text-13">
    <span class="cf-footer-item sm:block sm:mb-1">Cloudflare Ray ID: <strong class="font-semibold">7694d98e289d2d9d</strong></span>
    <span class="cf-footer-separator sm:hidden">&bull;</span>
    <span id="cf-footer-item-ip" class="cf-footer-item hidden sm:block sm:mb-1">
      Your IP:
      <button type="button" id="cf-footer-ip-reveal" class="cf-footer-ip-reveal-btn">Click to reveal</button>
      <span class="hidden" id="cf-footer-ip">34.121.123.15</span>
      <span class="cf-footer-separator sm:hidden">&bull;</span>
    </span>
    <span class="cf-footer-item sm:block sm:mb-1"><span>Performance &amp; security by</span> <a rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://www.cloudflare.com/5xx-error-landing" id="brand_link" target="_blank">Cloudflare</a></span>
    
  </p>
  <script>(function(){function d(){var b=a.getElementById("cf-footer-item-ip"),c=a.getElementById("cf-footer-ip-reveal");b&&"classList"in b&&(b.classList.remove("hidden"),c.addEventListener("click",function(){c.classList.add("hidden");a.getElementById("cf-footer-ip").classList.remove("hidden")}))}var a=document;document.addEventListener&&a.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",d)})();</script>
</div><!-- /.error-footer -->


    </div><!-- /#cf-error-details -->
  </div><!-- /#cf-wrapper -->

  <script>
  window._cf_translation = {};
  
  
</script>

<script>(function(){var js = "window['__CF$cv$params']={r:'7694d98e289d2d9d',m:'Ug4tKt_zSdRTQJrjFywLM7_Z2MB7yHT1n5bRWFstdlw-1668314641-0-AZU8lfb9aFFCd+ZmQt6Vjn3AovxApfXMHgGS7YOaj8rHDc6OouziAPrMKsqb/Qi2mn8r0hPyfhdjM4pi+e8mb4mAlQqjhnox9Ae1ZveVQfaRuyb6koLTnMwvWSGaC2lgnHHNLDzSO8DlYQGZGA9pR5o=',s:[0x80a034910e,0x0759096037],u:'/cdn-cgi/challenge-platform/h/b'};var now=Date.now()/1000,offset=14400,ts=''+(Math.floor(now)-Math.floor(now%offset)),_cpo=document.createElement('script');_cpo.nonce='',_cpo.src='/cdn-cgi/challenge-platform/h/b/scripts/alpha/invisible.js?ts='+ts,document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(_cpo);";var _0xh = document.createElement('iframe');_0xh.height = 1;_0xh.width = 1;_0xh.style.position = 'absolute';_0xh.style.top = 0;_0xh.style.left = 0;_0xh.style.border = 'none';_0xh.style.visibility = 'hidden';document.body.appendChild(_0xh);function handler() {var _0xi = _0xh.contentDocument || _0xh.contentWindow.document;if (_0xi) {var _0xj = _0xi.createElement('script');_0xj.nonce = '';_0xj.innerHTML = js;_0xi.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(_0xj);}}if (document.readyState !== 'loading') {handler();} else if (window.addEventListener) {document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', handler);} else {var prev = document.onreadystatechange || function () {};document.onreadystatechange = function (e) {prev(e);if (document.readyState !== 'loading') {document.onreadystatechange = prev;handler();}};}})();</script></body>
</html>
```

For some reason it gives me the html of a website? Im not too sure about what the error means as I am new to Discord bot developing.

Comment: Repl.it is a shared service for running code, and all users of repl.it share repl.it's IP addresses for outbound traffic. Furthermore, chances are that *malicious* users have tried to use repl.it for spam and other harmful activities, thus leading to that IP being likely blocked either at the Cloudflare or the Discord level.

You should instead be running your Discord bot either on your local workstation, or on a server that you control.

Comment: Could I suggest you to get a free server at [cloud.oracle.com](https://cloud.oracle.com/) ? it will require a credit card to check you're not a bot, with a transaction of around 1$ they reimburse after a couple of days. I'm using an Ubuntu for six months for my bot and I have no issue with them.

Answer (score 1):

There is many reasons why you can get rate-limited from the Discord API. The official info is listed [here](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/rate-limits).

From your post, you said you were using replit. Replit is actually not all that good for hosting bots (but of course its easy, cheap/free, and friendly for beginners). This is for multiple reasons, including: Source code for your bot is public, relies on website being up (which goes down semi-frequently), and the biggest is **you share an IP with other replit users**. < This is most likely your problem. Your replit IP is banned from the Discord API, not necessarily your *bot*.

No worries, the fix for this is extremely simple. On the right-hand side (or bottom depending on the layout), you'll see another tab named `shell` (see image). Go to here, and enter in the command `kill 1`. That's it. Just do that, and it should just kill your current IP and replace it with a new one from replit.

The reason why this happens is because other replit users might also being hosting on a bot on the same IP and calling to the Discord API, which counts towards the amount of requests available before you're blocked.

[image]